# How do I resolve this timeout error when trying to connect to my school's instance of GitLab with Git?

Tags: git, powershell, gitlab, ssh-keys

I have been trying to connect to my school's Gitlab instance through Git using SSH on my PC, but I keep getting a timeout error. I am following all the tutorials and it doesn't seem to be working and I don't know why. I have also ensured I have added the SSH key I generated here properly to my school GitLab account. Here are the steps I have taken, with sensitive data revoked:

```
PS C:\Users\brianna> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "MY EMAIL"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\brianna/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\brianna/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\brianna/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
> REVOKED FOR PRIVACY
The key's randomart image is:
> REVOKED FOR PRIVACY
PS C:\Users\brianna> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
> REVOKED FOR PRIVACY
PS C:\Users\brianna> ssh -T git@gitlab.MYSCHOOLDOMAIN.ca
ssh: connect to host gitlab.MYSCHOOLDOMAIN.ca port 22: Connection timed out
PS C:\Users\brianna> ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.MYSCHOOLDOMAIN.ca
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/brianna/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 
'C:\\Users\\brianna/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 
'C:\\Users\\brianna/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug2: resolving "gitlab.MYSCHOOLDOMAIN.ca" port 22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.MYSCHOOLDOMAIN.ca [IP.ADDRESS] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, 
io:00000266FA540080
debug1: connect to address IP.ADDRESS port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host gitlab.MYSCHOOLDOMAIN.ca port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from?  Is it possible you are sitting in a corporate environment where outbound ssh connections are blocked?

Comment: Nope! I'm in my apartment

Comment: Are you able to ssh to ANY host, or is it just the school?  Perhaps they limit outside use to certain providers.

Comment: when i use this same key to try to connect to my regular gitlab using "ssh -T git@gitlab.com", it tells me that it cannot verify the authenticity of the host and then it says permission denied (publickey). And I did add the ssh key to my normal gitlab as well.

Comment: That means it's specific to the school.  If you have an IT support line, that's your next call.

Comment: The config file is missing : C:/Users/brianna/.ssh/config